# How does GRE interface route packet to remote endpoint

Tags: linux, linux-networking, bridge, linux-kernel, gre

I have the following topology which I configured to run a GRE tunnel between my Desktop and the wireless router.
[image]

On the PC:

```
ip link add l2gre0 type gretap remote 192.168.0.103 local 192.168.0.10
```

On the Router:

```
ip link add l2gre0 type gretap remote 192.168.0.10 local 192.168.0.103
```

My client obtained an IP address of `10.10.10.102` from the DHCP server on PC. I try to ping the gateway IP `10.10.10.1` from my client. The ping succeeds.

What I want to understand is how the software routes this Ping packet across from `lan0` to `l2gre0` (both under bridge `br0`) and then crossing over to `eth0` over the wire to `enp3s0` (on the PC).

I took packet captures on `lan0` and I could see that capture showed an ethernet frame.
Then I took packet capture on `l2gre0` (on Wireless router). I could see the same frame as seen in `lan0`. which means `br0` repeated the frame from `lan0` to `l2gre0`.

If I take packet capture on eth0 interface, GRE encapsulation has already happened, which means between l2gre0 and eth0 the software stack attached to l2gre0 might have encapsulated the frame. But l2gre0 has only the idea about remote 192.168.0.10 and local 192.168.0.103 endpoints, so how did it decide that this packet (dest IP: 10.10.10.1) need to be encapsulated ?

Routes on the Wireless router:

```
/ # ip r
default via 192.168.0.10 dev eth0
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.32.107
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.103
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct site to post this question, will wait for few days else post on unix stackexchange. or superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the `lan0` and `l2gre0` are **bridged**, packet is forwarded from `lan0` to `l2gre0`, and it would be internally (by the kernel "`br_flood`/`br_forward`") pushed on the `l2gre0` transmit path via  "**ipgre_xmit**" where first **encapsulation** will happen and then the **route** **lookup** will happen for outer destination IP address which will push the packet out of `eth0` interface.

Answer (score 1):

> But l2gre0 has only the idea about remote 192.168.0.10 and local 192.168.0.103 endpoints, so how did it decide that this packet (dest IP: 10.10.10.1) need to be encapsulated ?

It didn't. The endpoints you're talking about are `tunnel source address` (192.168.0.103) and `tunnel destination address` (192.168.0.10). These are addresses that are used by kernel to send and receive encapsulated payload, they do not participate in kernel routing as such.

What exactly happens here is that your kernel IP stack routes packets destined to `10.10.10.1` out of your GRE tunnel just because it is a directly connected IP interface `l2gre0` with this address assigned as it's remote peer `tunnel remote address`. Likewise your `l2gre0` interface has `tunnel local address`, these are addresses assigned to the tunnel interface itself, think of them as "names for the local and remote side inside the tunnel", you can get them with `ip a l` on most modern distributions.

Whatever gets routed into the GRE tunnel by the kernel gets encapsulated and sent to the `tunnel destination address`, the interface doesn't check what payload it was given (just like any other interface doesn't) and send that out for the remote side to deal with it.

Comment: "ip a l" shows only this: 23: l2gre0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:56:9d:b0:b5:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: "kernel IP stack routes packets destined to 10.10.10.1 out of your GRE tunnel" but there is no route specifying this. How does kernel know that it is directly connected next-hop via l2gre0